# Apache Spark to query directly a Splunk search result

Tags: csv, apache-spark, splunk, splunk-query

Small question regarding an integration between Apache Spark and Splunk please.

Currently, I am doing a search query in Splunk. The result is quite big. Then, I need to perform some kind of data analytics from it.

Therefore, each time I get the result, I dump the search result as CSV from the Splunk UI.

Then, I manually download the CSV.

What I have tried:
I have ready a Spark job that will parse the CSV, the one from previous step, the Splunk search result. The Spark job will then use Spark SQL to load the CSV as table, and perform computation, very happy.

Basically, Splunk search result, very happy. Spark loading and doing map reduce on the csv, very happy.

However, I feel like this is very "stupid" as I am downloading manually each and every time a CSV.

May I ask, how can I connect Spark directly to Splunk search result please?

Thank you

Comment: If Spark can issue rest call, you can use the Splunk REST API to get data out. Curious, though - why not do your "data analytics" *in* Splunk itself?

Comment: Curious, though - why not do your "data analytics" in Splunk itself? -> this is actually a great question  we need to leverage some of the SparkML lib, and make some http requests on the result data to third arty API etc, therefore, Spark seems to be fit for the job